# How can I add variable inside RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

I am not finding solution to add variable inside following RegEx

```
val.replace(/[^\d.]/gm,'')
```

Basically I need to change the `.` to variable.
Something like

```
val.replace("/[^\d"+sepaeator+"]"/gm,'')
```

Comment: Use the constructor `new RegExp`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RegExp` instance ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)):

```
const regex = new RegExp(`[^\d${separator}]`, 'gm');
val.replace(regex, '');
```

Comment: Exact duplicates should not be answered, but closed.

Comment: @trincot, Accepted. I should have searched before answering.